# How to Redirect Multiple CIDR Blocks on Apache 2.4

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need to deny access to all users except those coming through several specific IP ranges (CDN). However, I need to exclude the "www" versions of my subdomains from this rule because the "www" versions need to bypass the CDN (due to inherent limitations). I would like to do this in the most concise/simple way possible using the [syntax available with Apache HTTPD 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) (or later). Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond expr "! -R '(12.345.678.90/28|09.876.543.21/28)'"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This is currently causing a server error, I'm guessing due to incorrect syntax.

Comment: `%{REMOTE_HOST}` is incorrect, it should be `%{HTTP_HOST}`, but that wouldn't cause a 500 error. Check your error log to see what causes it. Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: Hi @Capsule, thanks for the suggestions! I can confirm that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. And here is the relevant output from the error log (with a few values substituted to match the example above): `[Sun Jun 18 18:49:34.496813 2017] [core:alert] [pid 9894] [client 198.xx.xx.xx:53119] /home/sitename/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: cannot compile expression " -R '(12.345.678.90/28|09.876.543.21/28)'": parsing of subnet/netmask failed, referer: http://example.com/`

Comment: maybe this way `expr "! -R '12.345.678.90/28' && ! -R '9.876.543.21/28'"`

Comment: Thanks @Deadooshka! That seems very close. I'm no longer getting the 500 error. However, it seems like this particular method would require the correct IP range to be first in the list. If it's not first, I get the "Forbidden" error. So somehow it's not separating the ranges into proper "or" statements. Obviously there's no telling which IP will be used from the CDN at any given time.

Comment: and finally this: `expr "!(-R '127.0.0.0/8' || -R '192.0.0.0/8')"`

Comment: @Deadooshka, yes that's it! Works perfectly, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct (and most efficient) syntax for redirecting multiple CIDR blocks using a RewriteRule, in the context of the original question (thanks @Deadooshka!):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond expr "!(-R '127.0.0.0/8' || -R '192.0.0.0/8')"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```